# Firebase how to read wildcard node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm having trouble understanding how to reference and read wildcard node that has value.

**RTDB** (Can I have a sample path reference?):

[image: Can I have a sample path reference?]

What I've done :

```
     //  Define your RTDB Reference
    const rtdbReference = admin.database().ref("Sensor MQ7");
    const mq7ref = rtdbReference.child("-NHi7dBPMlVi6hXrnI03");
    const valref = mq7ref.child("MQ7");

    //  Fetch the data
    const snap = await valref.get();
    const snapValue = snap.val();

   //  Inject snapvalue in the response
   return res.status(200).send({
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id,
      text: `${first_name}\n${receivedMessage}\n${snapValue}`,
    });
```

**The output** : [Eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN1jo.png)

How do I make it so that it reads any wildcard node and output everything. Right now it only reads individual node when I specify it. Please help because I've been going at this since morning now its 10pm and if possible please explain like I'm 5 because I'm really really new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and log all nodes under `Sensor MQ7`, you can do:

```
const reference = admin.database().ref("Sensor MQ7");

const snapshot = await reference.get();

snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    console.log(childSnapshot.child("MQ7").val());
});
```

In here:

- `snapshot` contains a snapshot of all data under the `Sensor MQ7` nodes.
- `snapshot.forEach()` loops over the child nodes of the snapshot.
- `child("MQ7")` then gets the snapshot for that specific property.
- `.val()` gets its value.

Comment: alright i got it to work but now how do i pass the console.log(childSnapshot.child("MQ7").val()); to inject it to text: `${first_name}\n${receivedMessage}\n${snapValue}`,? I can't output the result into telegram